# Execute EOF command remotely in one line

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

I am facing a problem. If I execute this command, it works normally, but I need to execute it using SSH connection. Is there a way to do it in just one line of command? Thank you for your attention.

```
direct << EOF
selstat startt=(today) recids=pred;
EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking about one-line
[Here Documents](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

This is possible using
[Here Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings).

For example :

```
command >"$HOME/myfile" <<<'mytext'
```

This will send the string `mytext` to `command` on its standard input,
and it will write the string to the file `$HOME/myfile` through
the redirection of its standard output.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This is really what I needed!